# module has no attribute "push"

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, methods, python-2.x

I'm trying to add elements to a stack in another file but I am encountering an error.

Here is the class I'm importing:

```
class Empty(Exception): 
    """Error attempting to access an element from an empty container.""" 
    pass

class Stack_PlistLR: 
    def __init__ (self): 
        """Create an empty stack.""" 
        self._data = [ ] # nonpublic list instance 

    def __len__(self): 
        """Return the number of elements in the stack."""
        return len(self._data)

    def isEmpty(self): 
        """Return True if the stack is empty.""" 
        return len(self._data) == 0

    def push(self, e): 
        """Add element e to the top of the stack.""" 
        self._data.append(e)    # new item stored at end of list

    def top(self): 
        """Return (but do not remove) the element at the top of the stack. Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty. """ 
        if self.isEmpty():
            raise Empty('Stack is empty') 
        return self._data[-1] # the last item in the list

    def pop(self): 
        """Remove and return the element from the top of the stack (i.e., LIFO). Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty. """ 
        if self.isEmpty():
            raise Empty("Stack is empty") 
        return self._data.pop( )    # remove last item from list


    def __str__(self):
        str_s = ""

        for e in self._data:
            str_s+=str(e)+" "

        return str_s.strip()
```

My current code:

```
import Stack_PlistLR as s2

s2.push(14)
print(s2)
```

Error message I am getting:

> AttributeError: module 'Stack_PlistLR' has no attribute 'push'

Clearly the class has a push attribute? How do I remedy this problem?

Comment: you want `from Stack_PlistLR import Stack_PlistLR` + `s2 = Stack_PlistLR()`

Comment: You need to create an instance of the class otherwise you're attempting to access the static methods (which push is not)

Comment: You're confusing a Module with a class it contains. You also have to create an object first.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things going on here, it looks like:

1. From your import statement, it's apparent that you have a class named `Stack_PlistLR` inside a module, `Stack_PlistLR.py`.
2. You need to *instantiate* an instance of the class an an object rather than just referring to the method without instantiation, as you do now.

I.e.:

```
from Stack_PlistLR import Stack_PlistLR

s2 = Stack_PlistLR()
s2.push(14)
print(s2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are importing the file Stack_PlistLR as s2. Now s2 has Stack_PlistLR and Empty clases.

You can see it by doing print(dir(s2))

```
['Empty', 'Stack_PlistLR', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', 
'__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
```

If you want to use the Stack_PlistLR of s2. You should instatiate and Stack_PlistLR and then use it. Here is a code snippet:

```
import Stack_PlistLR as s2

s = s2.Stack_PlistLR()

s.push(14)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of the class and then call `.push()` on that instance

You can see from the method header, it accepts `self` as a parameter. This means that it requires an instance to execute

```
def push(self, e):
```

Your code would be as follows:

```
from Stack_PlistLR import Stack_PlistLR
s2 = Stack_PlistLR()
s2.push(14)
print(s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The class is not the module. It's an object in the module's namespace, so if you have imported the module as `s2` then it will be `s2. Stack_PlistLR` in your program.